# Force vba to wait for sql query to execute before continuing

Tags: excel, vba, ado

This seems to be a fairly common problem but none of the the solutions I've found seem to work.

I'm grabbing some data from SQL Server and copying it into a worksheet. Then I want to copy a range from the new data and do other stuff with it. All of this happens in a single vba function.

My problem is when the function is run from Excel it moves onto the second part of the function without waiting for the query to return the required data.

Of course the function works fine when I run it from the vba IDE.

```
Dim a As New ADODB.Connection
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset

a.Open (connStr)
Set r = a.Execute(sqlstr)

sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset r

'please wait here until the proc has executed?

checkData = sht.Range("A2").Value
```

When I run the function from Excel checkData is always empty, when I run it with F5 it always has the required data.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a worksheet function?  It won't work since a UDF can only return a value - it can't update a sheet directly.

Comment: @TimWilliams, yes I'm doing this in a vba function where sqlStr is a sql stored procedure that returns the required data.

Comment: Then just use `checkData = r.Fields(0).Value` unless there's more data from the recordset you need. If you need the other data then you're going to have to find some way of running the code other than through a UDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Dim a As New ADODB.Connection
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset

a.Open (connStr)
Set r = a.Execute(sqlstr)

Do
  'Wait
Loop Until Not r Is Nothing

sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset r

checkData = sht.Range("A2").Value
```

Alternatively, if this fails, you could try testing some property of r, like EOF or BOF, and if an error occurs, or you get an unexpected value you know the data hasn't yet loaded. For example:

```
Dim a As New ADODB.Connection
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset

a.Open (connStr)
Set r = a.Execute(sqlstr)

On Error Resume Next
Do
  Err.Clear
  r.EOF 'Put your test here, you might test rowcount or similar.
        'I've simply asked for the EOF property and ignored the result, I'm 
        'not sure if this will work in your case. Some testing may be required.
While Err.Num <> 0
On Error GoTo 0 'Or whatever you previously had this set to

sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset r

checkData = sht.Range("A2").Value
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @mkingston. Unfortunately the loop doesn't seem to make any difference. For the second solution, I already check if data is returned before doing the CopyFromRecordSet as part of my standard ado snippet, it seems like the function is running it in the background and continuing onto checkData.

Comment: @Skrealin I thought that might've been a little too obvious. I'd suggest putting some debug.print lines in your copyfromrecordset function to check that it's actually getting to every part of the code. If it is, output variable values to check everything's read/processed correctly.

Comment: The number of times I've assumed code is running in a certain way and found out it isn't. I think this is especially true when you're in a scripting language in someone else's environment; often the underlying objects are doing things you don't expect and if you don't have a good understanding of them it's easy to miss things.

Comment: After a ton of debugging, it turned out to be in another section of code that had been working happily for months before I tried to add this new stuff. Thanks for the help, at least I now know a lot more about recordsets!

Comment: Well, I don't think I really had much to do with it, but I'm glad you've sorted it out! :)

Answer (score 11):

Try using:

```
Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
```

after you execute the SQL, but before you copy the RecordSet

```
Set r = a.Execute(sqlstr)
    Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone
sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset r
```

Comment: Actually this should be marked as the correct answer.
I had the same issue with a web query refresh, that the subsequent calculations were performed before the data was downloaded from the web site. After adding the statement Applicaton.CalculateUntilAsnycQueriesDone it is waiting until the web query refresh finished.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. Instead of setting up the data source in code, set it up on the target worksheet as a data connection (Excel menu Data | From Other Sources | etc.). Once a connection object named "(Default)" is created you tap it in code along these lines:

```
  With ActiveWorkbook
    .Connections("(Default)").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    .Connections("(Default)").OLEDBConnection.CommandText = sqlstr
    .RefreshAll
    ' do more stuff
    ' will wait for .RefreshAll to complete because .BackgroundQuery = false
  End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `r.movelast` after the execute to make sure all the rows are returned.

Something like

```
Set r = a.Execute(sqlstr)

If Not r.EOF Then
    r.MoveLast
End If

sht.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset r
```

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of andy holaday, I got this to work by unchecking "Enable background refresh" in the external data range properties. Disabling this feature forces excel to wait while the query is run.

Answer (score 0):

But if there is no recordset being returned I found this code will wait until the SQL code returns before going to the next VBA statement.  Handy when there is dependency by one command on another or if you need an entire data set created before moving on.

```
Dim Con As ADODB.Connection
Dim CmdTxt As String

Set Con = New Connection
Con.ConnectionString = ThisWorkbook.GetYourConnectString()
Con.Open

CmdTxt = "EXEC db.schema.StoredProc1 @Param1 = 'Yes'"
ExecuteSql Con, CmdTxt, True, True

CmdTxt = "EXEC db.schema.StoredProc2 @Param1 = 'No'"
ExecuteSql Con, CmdTxt, True, True

MsgBox "Both commands completed sequentially"
```

The code for ExecuteSql is:

```
Public Function ExecuteSql(Con As ADODB.Connection, sql As String, _
    Optional StopOnError As Boolean = True, _
    Optional WaitUntilDone As Boolean = False) As String

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

With cmd

    .CommandType = 1
    .CommandText = sql
    .ActiveConnection = Con

    If WaitUntilDone = True Then
        .CommandTimeout = 0 'set timeout to unlimited
        .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords 'no records value speeds up internal code
    Else
        .Execute
    End If

End With

ExecuteSql = ""

Exit Function
```